# What kind of caulk should I use to seal up spalling separating from steel porch ceiling

Tags: concrete, deck, steel, stucco, rust-removal

I'd like to do some temporary quick patches to prevent worsening rust and separation of spalling/stucco ceiling underneath a steel outdoor porch/deck.  One on the first floor is kinda bad so will require it to come down and be replaced, but the 2nd floor is still small and can perhaps be patched.  What kind of caulk can I use to waterproof seal and optionally to help glue the corner up and prevent the rest of it from sagging further?

Here's pictures of the first floor and the 2nd floor
[image: 1st floor deck ceiling]

Additionally, what kind of contractor should I be looking for if I want the first floor ceiling to come down and be replaced?  What is a reasonsable price to remove ceiling, scrub rust and either leave with rust proof bare steel or new concrete like ceiling?

Comment: What am I looking at in the second picture? Even if you managed to seal the front of image #1 you might actually cause yourself a standing water issue if the water gets in another way and has no escape route.

Comment: picture 2 is a close up, looking up at the edge of the 2nd floor ceiling - the black is the steel frame and the gray is the concrete or stucco that is peeling away from the corner.  You can also see some of the rusting mesh for the concrete or stucco underneath.  Picture 1 is lost cause I think since it's so big - but picture 2 is smaller and maybe amenable to just a caulk?

Comment: Prices are off topic as they are obsolete the next week. As far as your rusty metal clean the rust off and paint with a zinc rich paint like cold galvanizing compound , unless it is stainless it will rust if bare. The ceiling in the porch looks more like plywood with some stucco on it, well I can’t see the stucco but I have never seen stucco come loose like that even expanded steel, but I have seen plywood made to look like stucco do this.